# Comparing a generic return type to a similar generic variable in Java

Tags: java, generics, comparison

I am writing a generic linked list in Java and have everything working except for one problem.

The list nodes hold a variable "data" of type E and I have a variable "tempData" also of type E in the general linked list code. Data type E is will be determined by the program using the linked list.

What I am trying to do is retrieve the variable from the linked node "data" by calling the node function getData() and store it in a variable called tempData.

Here is the current code:

```
tempData = firstNode.getData();
```

My problem is that when compiling I get the error saying that they are "incompatible types". I know at run-time they will be the same data type, but how do I satisfy the syntax for it to compile?

I have tried putting the code in:

```
if( firstNode.getData() instanceof tempData.getClass() )
```

But it didn't work as where the class should be no methods are allowed to be called. I also tried the following, which worked, but I still got the original compilation error.

```
if( (firstNode.getData()).getClass == tempData.getClass() )
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

EDIT 3-28-13

Declaration for tempData is "E tempData;"

Declaration for firstNode is "private ListNode firstNode;"

Declaration for data in firstNode is "private E data;" which is gotten by .getData();

Header for LinkedList class "public class LinkedList E"

Header for ListNode class "public class ListNode E"

Both Es in the headers have less than and greater than symbols around them, they just are not showing up when posted.

Comment: Can you add to your question the declarations of both tempData and firstNode?  Would make it easier to see the problem I suspect.

Comment: @Jules  E tempData;
And in firstNode (and all nodes) private E data; which is returned by .getData()

Comment: And how are firstNode itself and its getData() method declared?

Comment: And firstNode is presumably declared as `ListNode<E> firstNode`, yes? (to get the code to show up properly, use backward single quotes around it).

Comment: It turns out I forgot to add the '<E>' after ListNode, thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

One possible answer would be to store a Class object in your list, like so:

```
Class<E> clazz;
```

Then initialize this with the correct object in the constructor:

```
public MyList(Class<E> clazz) {
   this.clazz = clazz;
}

...

new MyList<E>(E.class);
```

You can then use this class object to cast objects to the correct type: `clazz.cast(firstNode.getData())`.

There are probably better solutions, but in the worst case this approach works.

Comment: When trying your code I got several errors so I changed it to:
Class c  = tempData.getClass();

Only problem is casting still isn't working as I got the following error
LinkedList.java:115: error: incompatible types
        tempData = c.cast(firstNode.getData());

So I tried casting both to the same type and got
LinkedList.java:115: error: unexpected type
        c.cast(tempData) = c.cast(firstNode.getData());
              ^
Am I doing what you intended wrong?

Comment: I've added some more explanation of what I mean.  Does this help?

Comment: I would love to try what you wrote, but since this is for an assignment for which a UML diagram has been provided, I am not allowed to change the parameters of the constructors